# Group Wise Data populate

Tags: sql, plsql

I am working in Report , and want to show the Order no only once within the Group.

I have tried using loop and assigning the value to temp variable and then comparing

```
declare
l_cnt number;
cursor c1 is select * from zz_employees;
begin
dbms_output.put_line ('Order |-' || 'Material | -' || 'Salesperson |');
for i in c1
loop
  l_cnt := i.ordernumber;
  if l_cnt = i.ordernumber then 
        --dbms_output.put_line (l_cnt);
         dbms_output.put_line (l_cnt || '-' || i.materialno || '-' || i.salesperson);
  else
  dbms_output.put_line (i.ordernumber || '-' || i.materialno || '-' || i.salesperson);
  end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Current Table Data :-

```
1001    9000001 James
1001    9000002 Tom
1001    9000003 Harry
1002    9000004 Voret
1002    9000005 Kzahunar
1003    9000006 Zari
1004    9000007 Neblas
1004    9000008 Anthony
```

Expected Result

```
1001    9000001 James
        9000002 Tom
        9000003 Harry
1002    9000004 Voret
        9000005 Kzahunar
1003    9000006 Zari
1004    9000007 Neblas
        9000008 Anthony
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your loop a bit as you print the value no matter what:

```
loop
  if l_cnt = i.ordernumber then 
    dbms_output.put_line ('    -' || i.materialno || '-' || i.salesperson);
  else
    dbms_output.put_line (i.ordernumber || '-' || i.materialno || '-' || i.salesperson);
    l_cnt := i.ordernumber;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Alternatively you can ommit the values directly in the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ordernumber  = MAX(ordernumber) over (ORDER BY ROWNUM 
                                                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 preceding AND 1 preceding) 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE ordernumber  
       END ordernumber 
     , materialno 
     , salesperson
  FROM zz_employees
```

Comment: Both the Solution working as Expected .. Thank you so much !